# Converting format and CRS of many shapefiles to kml (or csv, json..)

Tags: qgis, shapefile, layers, export

I tried to use QGIS to transform shp files in kml and to translate the CRS to use in a google maps application.
My problem is that I have a lot of shp files that i can open in a bulk manner by drag and drop but i can only export one layer at a time.

I have used the MMQGIS plugin to merge layers and export one that containes all. This works fine, except that the only way i can keep track of the shp files is by their file name (the objname is truncated to 10 chars), and when i merge the layes the order gets somehow scrambled and i cannot make sense of the what is which.

So, bottom line, how can i convert a lot of shp files (and also to change the CRS) in a more friendly format (kml, csv, json, etc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the command line [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html), you can bulk convert your shps and change the CRS into [many different formats](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_formats.html) including kml, json, geojson, and csv.

For a Romanian CRS called Stereo 70 the source CRS (SRS in this case or EPSG), I think should be [3844](http://spatialreference.org/ref/?search=Stereo+70). To transform to Google Maps, use `-t_srs 4326` in your command.